# Short story: Political story, San Francisco wins drawing for deciding morals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think the short story is circa 2005 or so, a time when society has agreed to determine political and moral policy through a lottery system, spinning a wheel - definitely a Wheel of Fortune motif. It is told from a conservative point of view, and at the end San Francisco is awarded morality laws. I *think* I read it in S&SF or Asimov's or Analog at that time. The protagonist is a critical person attending the drawings, and conservative cities begin "winning" control of different political topics, such as birth control, guns, freedom of speech.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you identify any elements of the story that make it SF or fantasy?  Where did you read it?

Comment: Hey there! That's some info already; but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, it's "circa 2005", but was it published way earlier maybe (say the 60s)? Was it online (if so, any recollection of the site?), in an anthology (any recollection of the cover?), in a magazine? What language was it in? Stuff like this, as well as any other info you could think of. Anything might help. Cheers :)

Comment: @DavidW I'm guessing this is the same SFF topicness as the "everyone is granted $1 million at birth" from a couple of days ago. (from where I stand, both are on-topic)

Comment: Author Starhawk?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great match - it's individual morality that's in play, not societal, and the reviews don't mention a wheel - but at least a partial match is "Bambi Steaks" by Richard A. Lovett, published in *Analog*, May 2007.

It's most *definitely* got a conservative point of view, according to a [couple](https://www.tangentonline.com/print--monthly-reviewsmenu-259/analog-reviewsmenu-54/1072-analog-may-2007) of [reviews](https://www.oocities.org/evelynleeper/rev-l2.htm) I've found.

Individuals from "Red" states are swapped with people from "Blue" states, apparently paired up by some lottery or game.  Of course the "Blue" viewpoint character typifies all the negative stereotypes of "whiny liberals," and the hard-working, noble, independent "Red" characters have all of the positive features they would pride themselves on, and none of the negative ones.

> Lovett's story is anything but subtle, [...] his depiction of the narrator, a latte server in a coffee shop who studied literature in college, and the arrogant, smug, self-righteous, whiny, ill-informed caricature that conservative critics make Blue Staters out to be.
>
> As it happens, though, only the Blue Staters come in for such treatment.  [...] every positive stereotype of the Red Staters is presented as true, every negative one punctured, deflated, subverted.  Just as talk radio voices like Sean Hannity and Laura Ingraham would have them be, their inhabitants are politer, harder-working, and more decent than their Blue counterparts...
>
> <sub>From the [Tangent review](https://www.tangentonline.com/print--monthly-reviewsmenu-259/analog-reviewsmenu-54/1072-analog-may-2007)</sub>

I'm not sure if this is a good match or not, but I haven't come across many stories that hammer the Red-state-good, Blue-state-bad that hard.